# toggle on click but doesn't slide back down once clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got a jQuery toggle that seems to work, however when i click it again, it doesn't seem to want to slide down upon it being clicked. I even tried to click the others.

What am I doing wrong? I've had a go at it, but maybe im missing something relatively simple.

javascript:

```
$(function() {          
                $("li.subMenu").click(function() {      
                    $(".subMenu-link").slideUp("normal");   
                    $(this).next().slideDown();
                });     
                $(".subMenu-link").not(':first').hide();
            });
```

HTML:

```
<li class="subMenu">                                    
    <i class="lock"></i> 
    <span class="title">User Account</span>
    <span class="toggle">+</span>
        <ul class="subMenu-link">
            <li>One Link</li>
            <li>One Link</li>
            <li>One Link</li>
            <li>One Link</li>
        </ul> 
</li>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qj58Lm5q/)

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/qj58Lm5q/1/

Comment: You're calling $(this).next(), but li.submenu is $(this) and it has no next().

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
$(this).next();
```

Selects the next li subMenu Item, which you could say is already "down" (visible). You probably want to drop down the unordered list within the subMenu Item. You can access it through children:

```
$(this).next().children('.subMenu-link').slideDown();
```

If clicked on the first one it would hide the first one, then show the second one. If clicked on the second one it would hide the second one and show the third one. However if you'd click the third one, it would simply slideUp that one and slideDown nothing, since there's no fourth element.

If what you are trying to do is show one and hide the others, you could use siblings instead:

```
$("li.subMenu").click(function() {      
                $(this).children(".subMenu-link").slideDown("normal");  
                $(this).siblings().children('.subMenu-link').slideUp();
            });
```